# can't install my signed firefox addon : signature verification failed

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, signing

I've made a web extensions addon and it works when loading it through about:debugging.

Now I'm using web-ext command and I issue `web-ext build` then upload the zip file to AMO, it correctly validates and signs it and I download the xpi file.

Now when I drag the xpi file and drop it into Addons page I see "add-on could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt" and In browser console I see :

> 1521507462608 addons.webextension.   WARN    Loading extension
>   'null': Reading manifest: Error processing update_url: An unexpected
>   property was found in the WebExtension manifest.
>   1521507462608 addons.webextension.   WARN    Loading extension
>   'null': Reading manifest: Error processing key: An unexpected property
>   was found in the WebExtension manifest.
>   1521507462622 addons.xpi  WARN    Add-on mtn@nas.sy is not correctly
>   signed.1521507462622  addons.xpi  WARN    Invalid XPI: signature
>   verification failed

I have to say that when uploading the first version of the extension it worked but on uploading subsequent versions I get this error.

So how to solve this issue ? I already tried uploading it multiple times with different versions.

### Edit

here is my manifest.json

```
{


"name": "NasMtnBarcode",
  "version": "1.2.5",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "an extension to make mtn able to use their barcodes from inside chrome,firefox and opera",
  "update_url": "http://0.0.0.0",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "src/background/background.js" ]
  },
  "key": "mykey",
  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "mtn@nas.sy"
    }
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "src/jquery.min.js",
        "src/inject/inject.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "src/inject/mtnViewer.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: They can probably help you in #webextensions on irc.mozilla.org.

Comment: Error processing update_url:  Are you using a valid https address? Maybe post your manifest?

Comment: @PaulHeil posted my manifest, anyway I tried removing update_url altogether and the same issue happens

Answer (score 0):

First issue I see is I don't believe "key" is a valid Firefox key.  Looks specific to Chrome and shouldn't be used anyway.  Second, "update_url" should be HTTPS and part of the applications key.

```
"applications": {
    "gecko": {
        "id": "mtn@nas.sy",
        "update_url": "https://0.0.0.0/test.json"
    }
},
```

Comment: I need the "key" because this extension is also a chrome extension

Comment: anyway I removed "key" and also "update_url" and still the same issue

Comment: Can you edit your post with the new console messages?